# Finding Sytem Level Processes that are running in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, process

How can I tell whether a process running on a device is system-level (like `Windows PowerShell`) or not (like `Discord.exe`) by getting the username of the process? I've tried using several libraries, but they don't supply the username of the process.

Comment: You can use the child_process module to run a cmd prompt and run the "taskList" command and capture its output with a command line such as `tasklist /V /FO csv`.  Details on the command line arguments to taskList [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist).

Comment: @jfriend00
Thanks this helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tasklist /V /FO csv` to get a CSV formatted output of the various processes running on Windows.  And, you can run that command with `child_process.spawn()`.  Here's an example:

```
const child_process = require('child_process');

const tasklist = child_process.spawn('tasklist', ['/V', '/FO', 'csv']);

tasklist.stdout.on('data', data => {
    console.log(data.toString());
}).on('error', err => {
    console.log(err);
});

tasklist.stderr.on('data', data => {
    console.log(data.toString());
});

tasklist.on('error', err => {
    console.log(err);
}).on('close', () => {
    console.log("done");
});
```

Other command line arguments for the `tasklist` command can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist).